# Finding the array Key that matched element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that is a result of a parsed json:

```
{
 "AKH":{
   "name": "Amonkhet",
   "code": "AKH",
   "releaseDate": "2017-04-28",
   "border": "black",
   "block": "Amonkhet",
   "type": "expansion"
   "cards": [
  {
  "artist": "Min Yum",
  "cmc": 5,
  "colorIdentity": [
    "W"
  ],
  "colors": [
    "White"
  ],
  "manaCost": "{3}{W}{W}",
  "multiverseid": 426703,
  "name": "Angel of Sanctions",
  "number": "1",
  "power": "3",
  "rarity": "Mythic Rare",
  "subtypes": [
    "Angel"
  ],
  "toughness": "4",
  "type": "Creature — Angel",
  "types": [
    "Creature"
  ]
},
  "SHM" : {
   "name": "Shadowmoor",
   "code": "SHM",
   "magicCardsInfoCode": "shm",
   "releaseDate": "2008-05-02",
   "border": "black",
   "type": "expansion",
   "block": "Shadowmoor",
   "cards": [
{
  "artist": "Kev Walker",
  "colors": [
    "White"
  ],
  "manaCost": "{W}",
  "name": "Apothecary Initiate",
  "number": "1",
  "power": "1",
  "rarity": "Common",
  "subtypes": [
    "Kithkin",
    "Cleric"
  ],
  "toughness": "1",
  "type": "Creature — Kithkin Cleric",
  "types": [
    "Creature"
  ]
},
```

Notice the key matches the code... this will ALWAYS be the case for this scenario.

I make elements from the names and codes

```
setList += "<a href='#' onClick='setLinks(this.id)' id=" + setCode + ">" + setName + "</a> " + "<br>"
```

and am now attempting to create a function that matches the ID (setCode) with the Key in my object.

right now I have a function that does find that card names and lists them all:

```
function cardPop(listings){
  var cards = listings.cards;
  for (var i=0; i < cards.length; i++){
    var card = cards[i];
    cardNum = Object.keys(cards)
  }

  $.each(cards, function(cardNum, cardListing) {
    cardName = cardListing.name
    console.log(cardName)
  });
};
```

But in reality, i'd like for that card population to only give the cards in the list that matches the link clicked.

```
function setLinks(clicked_id)
   if clicked_id == ?
```

I futzed around with a bunch of things.. and am sufficiently stumped. I've surfed stackoverflow and the almighty google, but I am having a hard time wording my question to get the correct results. Some things do get me close by no cigar. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

@gvmani.. Thank you so much for the help! Here is what I ended up with. Not the final product, but working for now!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/s7and', function (data) {
  json = data
  set_codes = Object.keys(data);
  for (var i=0; i < set_codes.length; i++){
  set = set_codes[i];
}
 $.each(data, function(set_codes, listings){
  setName = listings.name
  setCode = listings.code
  setPop(setCode, setName)
});
}); 
});  

//Set population
 function setPop(){
  var setList = "";
  setList += "<a href='#' onClick='setLinks(this.id)' id=" + setCode + ">" + setName + "</a> " + "<br>"
 $('.things').append(setList);
 };

 // Function to Generate Card List
 function setLinks(clicked_id){
  $.each(json, function(setCode, setListing) {
   $.each(setListing.cards,function(cardNum, cardListing){
    if(setListing.code === clicked_id){
    console.log(cardListing.name);
 }
 });
 });

}
```

Comment: Your code is hard to look at, please correct the indentation.

Comment: I corrected the indentation, but the syntax is still completely off. Could you copy+paste the actual data and code from the source

Comment: this JSON is invalid in all the countries in the World

Comment: Can you include something that got you close that we can base an answer on, instead of a block full of question marks you're hoping someone else will fill in?

Comment: @quirimmo, The JSON is valid, i was trying to avoid going through the pain in my ass to trim it down for here.. its not exactly a short list.

Comment: @Adrian, I have typed and erased so many things in the last 2 days that I can't even begin to know which ones got me close... The best I've done is make sure it does see the clicked_id Correctly, which it does.. but i have no clue in hell how to use that as a search through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post updated as per comment.

```js
var data =  {
  "AKH": {
   "name": "Amonkhet",
   "code": "AKH",
   "cards": [{
    "name": "1"
   }, {
    "name": "2"
   }]
  },
  "SHM": {
   "name": "Shadowmoor",
   "code": "SHM",
   "cards": [{
    "name": "3"
   }, {
    "name": "4"
   }]
  }
 }
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $.each(data, function(cardNum, cardListing) {
      
    $("<a href='#' onClick='setLinks(\""+cardNum+"\")' id=" + cardListing.code + ">" + cardListing.name + "</a> <br>").appendTo("#links");
    
  });



 });
 
 function setLinks(code){
 $("#cards").empty();
  $.each(data, function(cardNum, cardListing) {
    $.each(cardListing.cards,function(ind,card){
    if(cardListing.code === code){
    
    $("<a href='#'>" + card.name + "</a> <br>").appendTo("#cards");
    }
    });
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="links">

</div>
<div id="cards">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is backwards. Though I may be able to reverse it so I appreciate it.
What I'm looking for is it to make a list Not of the cards, but of the set codes, and then the set code is clicked, it then populates the list of cards within that set.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the Question with what I came up with! I appreciate the giant shove in the correct direction :)